# ntp, ntpsec, openntpd: which differences?

Tags: time, ntp

On my Ubuntu 20.04, I would like to use `ntpd` to perform a time synchronization. This program is not installed, but is present in 3 different packages.

```
Command 'ntpd' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install ntpsec    # version 1.1.8+dfsg1-4build1, or
apt install openntpd  # version 1:6.2p3-4
apt install ntp       # version 1:4.2.8p12+dfsg-3ubuntu4.20.04.1
```

Then, three questions:

- What are the difference between the three packages? Which one is the most recent? the most recommended? Is there one discontinued?
- What `ntpd` is actually doing?
- Are the three implementations  of `ntpd` in the three packages the same?

Answer (score 1):

> On my Ubuntu 20.04, I would like to use ntpd to perform a time synchronization. This program is not installed, but is present in 3 different packages.

No offense, but "No you do not want ntpd" :-)
I know people look for it as they are used to the old names, terms but since (wow I realize that is half a decade) [18.04 chrony has replaced ntpd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Chrony) as a better, faster and more maintainable solution.

[This doc](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp) should explain all you need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Those are three independent implementations of the Network Time Protocol.

ntpd is the daemon that keeps your time in sync with internet time servers.